# Using php im Mailchimp template

Tags: php, mailchimp

Is it possible to create a template with php in it. I'm trying to send all the subscribers in mailchimp a custom coupon with an unique code for a discount.

For example:

Hi Sven,

Your very own couponcode is [code imported from database].

I saw the podbox plugin buts that's a little to expensive and the mailchimp api guide wasn't really clear on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use PHP in a Mailchimp template.

You'd need to use their [Merge Tags](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheatsheet) and load the coupon codes as per-subscriber metadata, either via importing a CSV or by using the API.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to look into it again.